# Relationships in Django - how to filter data

Tags: django, filter, django-views, django-templates

I've looked at a lot of entries and I know how to filter simple relationships.
 Unfortunately, I'm stuck and I don't know how to filter my table data when one of the tables is a branch of a certain string.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Autor(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Incident(models.Model):
   group_no = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Department-leader(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="leader")
   department = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Group(models.Model):
   group_no = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

views.py

```
def get_author(user):
    qs = Autor.objects.filter(user=user)
    if qs.exists():
        return qs[0]
    return None

def show_all(request):
    show_all_records = Incident.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('-id')[:300]

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        autors_list = get_author(request.user)
        user_list = get_user_model()
        logged_user = get_object_or_404(user_list, username__exact=autors_list)
        
        (...)
        
        print("Logged user: " + str(logged_user.id))
    else:
        logged_user = ""


    context = {
        'show_all_records': show_all_records,
        'logged_user': logged_user,
    }

    return render(request, 'incident/all_records.html', context)
```

The ***show_all_records*** variable represents all the records of the ***Incident*** table and that is ok. 
The second thing I would like to display are entries for the logged in person i.e. all incidents in particular departments of the leader who is logged in.

[image]

If the tables were connected linearly, I would have no problem building this filter.
But how to make a filter for this layout of tables?

In pure SQL, it would look something like this:

```
select 
    bledy_bledy.nr_zlecenia,
    bledy_bledy.ilosc_bledow,
    bledy_gruparobocza.nr_grupy,
    auth_user.username,
    auth_user.id
from 
    bledy_bledy 
LEFT JOIN 
    bledy_lider_dzial
on
    bledy_bledy.nr_grupy_roboczej_id = bledy_lider_dzial.dzial_id
LEFT JOIN 
    bledy_gruparobocza
on
    bledy_lider_dzial.dzial_id = bledy_gruparobocza.id
LEFT JOIN 
    auth_user
on
    bledy_lider_dzial.user_id = auth_user.id
where
    auth_user.id = 4
```

**Can I count on some hint on how to build it?**

Comment: Do you have more than one leader in a group? if not, you can use OneToOne or simply add leader in the Group model with a FK to User.
Also "Department-leader" is not a valid class name, should be "DepartmentLeader"

Comment: Yes, each leader has several groups. For each group there will be at least 2 leaders.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you want.

```
user = request.user

# only need the primary keys of the group leaders for the next query
department_ids = user.leader.all().values_list('department_id', flat=True)

incidents = Incident.objects.filter( group_no_id__in= departments )
```

Also a suggestion: stick to Django conventions for naming foreign keys and related names. `leaders` not `leader` (because it refers to a plurality or set of leaders), and `group` not `group_no` because it refers to a `Group` object. (The actual FK/primary key value is obtained by appending `_id` to the field name, as used in the above. This is Django "magic".)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and tip, which turned out to be very helpful. For some minor error, I doubted the correctness of the filter. Thanks to your suggestion, I went through it again and it seems to work as expected.